# Want to get href and title from the table using Jsoup

Tags: android, html, parsing, jsoup

I want to parse Html table using Jsoup but I am having trouble getting my requried data from it. I want to get **href** and **title** from each row of this table but I am getting the whole data from the table.

```
<table class="FullWidth gv" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_Body_STUDENT_SSS_ctrl0_COURSE_REGISTRATION" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">S#</th>
        <th scope="col">Code</th>
        <th scope="col">Registered Course Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Credits</th>
        <th scope="col">Offered Course Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Class</th>
        <th scope="col">Teacher</th>
        <th scope="col">Fee</th>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Center">
                                1</td>
        <td class="NoWrap">GSC 220</td>
        <td class="Width33">Complex Variables &amp; Transforms</td>
        <td class="Center">3</td>
        <td class="Width33">Complex Variables &amp; Transforms</td>
        <td class="NoWrap">BCE-4 (A) MORNING</td>
        <td class="Width33">AMMAR AJMAL</td>
        <td>YES</td>
        <td>
            <a title="Complex Variables &amp; Transforms" class="a" href="Attendance.aspx?COID=21480" target="_blank">Attendance</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Alternating">
        <td class="Center">
                                2</td>
        <td class="NoWrap">CSC 221</td>
        <td class="Width33">Data Structure and Algorithm</td>
        <td class="Center">3</td>
        <td class="Width33">Data Structure and Algorithm</td>
        <td class="NoWrap">BCE-4 (A) MORNING</td>
        <td class="Width33">ABU BAKAR</td>
        <td>YES</td>
        <td>
            <a title="Data Structure and Algorithm" class="a" href="Attendance.aspx?COID=21478" target="_blank">Attendance</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Center">
                                3</td>
        <td class="NoWrap">CSL 221</td>
        <td class="Width33">Data Structures and Algorithm Lab</td>
        <td class="Center">1</td>
        <td class="Width33">Data Structures and Algorithm Lab</td>
        <td class="NoWrap">BCE-4 (A) MORNING</td>
        <td class="Width33">ABU BAKAR</td>
        <td>YES</td>
        <td>
            <a title="Data Structures and Algorithm Lab" class="a" href="Attendance.aspx?COID=21479" target="_blank">Attendance</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Alternating">
        <td class="Center">
                                4</td>
        <td class="NoWrap">CSC 220</td>
        <td class="Width33">Database Management System</td>
        <td class="Center">3</td>
        <td class="Width33">Database Management System</td>
        <td class="NoWrap">BCE-4 (A) MORNING</td>
        <td class="Width33">BUSHRA SABIR</td>
        <td>YES</td>
        <td>
            <a title="Database Management System" class="a" href="Attendance.aspx?COID=21481" target="_blank">Attendance</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Center">
                                5</td>
        <td class="NoWrap">CSL 220</td>
        <td class="Width33">Database Management System Lab</td>
        <td class="Center">1</td>
        <td class="Width33">Database Management System Lab</td>
        <td class="NoWrap">BCE-4 (A) MORNING</td>
        <td class="Width33">BUSHRA SABIR</td>
        <td>YES</td>
        <td>
            <a title="Database Management System Lab" class="a" href="Attendance.aspx?COID=21482" target="_blank">Attendance</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Alternating">
        <td class="Center">
                                6</td>
        <td class="NoWrap">CSC 320</td>
        <td class="Width33">Operating System</td>
        <td class="Center">3</td>
        <td class="Width33">Operating System</td>
        <td class="NoWrap">BCE-4 (A) MORNING</td>
        <td class="Width33">BUSHRA SABIR</td>
        <td>YES</td>
        <td>
            <a title="Operating System" class="a" href="Attendance.aspx?COID=21474" target="_blank">Attendance</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Center">
                                7</td>
        <td class="NoWrap">CSL 320</td>
        <td class="Width33">Operating System Lab</td>
        <td class="Center">1</td>
        <td class="Width33">Operating System Lab</td>
        <td class="NoWrap">BCE-4 (A) MORNING</td>
        <td class="Width33">BUSHRA SABIR</td>
        <td>YES</td>
        <td>
            <a title="Operating System Lab" class="a" href="Attendance.aspx?COID=21475" target="_blank">Attendance</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gvFooter">
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="Center">15</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
```

I am trying like this

```
 Document doce = Jsoup.connect(urlofthewebsite)
                .cookies(hashMap)
                .get();



Element tableheader = doce.select("table[id=ctl00_Body_STUDENT_SSS_ctrl0_COURSE_REGISTRATION}").first();

for(Element element : tableheader.children())
{
    System.out.println(element.text());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your example have typo at

```
select("table[id=ctl00_Body_STUDENT_SSS_ctrl0_COURSE_REGISTRATION}")
```

since you are ending attribute selector with `}` instead of `]`.

You avoid such errors with `id` start using `#identifier` instead of `[id=identifier]` and `.className` instead of `[class=className]`.

Also by calling

```
.select("table[id=ctl00_Body_STUDENT_SSS_ctrl0_COURSE_REGISTRATION]")
.first();
```

you are not getting first row from table (like headers), but *first table* with this `id` (since such elements - tables with specific id - your selector suppose to find).
If you want find headers simply pick them by selecting `th` tags like

```
Element table = doce.select("table#ctl00_Body_STUDENT_SSS_ctrl0_COURSE_REGISTRATION").first();
for(Element column : table.select("th")) {
    System.out.println(column.text());
}
```

Now based on

> I want to get **href** and **title** from each row of this table but I am getting the whole data from the table.

you may want to use something like

```
for (Element link : table.select("a")){
    System.out.println(link.attr("title")+" -> "+link.attr("href"));
    //you can also use abs:href to get absolute path
}
```